# Vaadin Tree Nodes (closed)

Tags: tree, vaadin, treenode

Does anybody know a API or something for **Vaadin** that i dont have to save the nodes as Strings to reidentify them?

*This is important for me because i'm working on a Programm on with the User chooses the Names and they are not static for ever.*

Would realy love something like:

```
Node node = new Node("Title");
Node node1 = new Node("Title1");
node.addNode(node1);
tree.addNode(node);
```

Thanks for every answere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in vaadin item identifiers do not have to be a String. They just have to be an object.

Maybe you are looking for the Tree component from Vaadin? https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.tree.html

Comment: Okay, and how is than the title or caption defined?

Comment: i do not know which component you are talking about. in general you can set the caption of every vaadin component with the setCaption() method.

Comment: not of a tree 'node' which is just addet like: tree.addItem(Object);   I search for something that i can then access to the node and set a child and so on.

Comment: If you don't define anything like setCaption(...) or similar, vaadin uses the toString() of the object as caption text